# Answered correctly, asker thanked and removed his question

Tags: discussion, support, questions

Here's [the question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25525132/cant-display-title-on-marker-in-android-google-map/25525406#25525406).

It's kind of weird that you can remove a question that has been answered.

My answer was correct however it didn't have any up-votes. But perhaps it didn't have the chance to receive any?

Furthermore the asker thanked me, and removed his question. That kind of discourages answering at all.

Can anyone explain to me why this behavior is allowed at all? Or at least give some examples when this is a good thing.

I'd rather that questions could be removed only when the available answers are all down-voted (not by the asker).

Comment: It's allowed but certainly not encouraged. I believe deleting an answered question is weighted much more heavily for imposing question bans as well, so should they keep doing it very soon they'll find that they've lost their privilege to ask questions.

Comment: An instance where the OP deleting their own question is a good thing is when the problem in the question was a typo or some "duh" type of mistake. I can't know what was going on in the OP's mind here but if their reaction when they saw your answer was "duh... I meant to put ``false`` there" then I'd say that deleting their own question was the right thing to do.

Comment: I don't think it's a mistyping. The API docs state, that one should return 'true' if the listener has consumed the event etc., so it should be clear, but Java APIs tend to have documentation style that is problematic to understand for a large spectrum of people. I don't know if the question really deserves downvotes, it's just asking for API clarification, in the end effect.

Comment: Sure, it's not what we want, but the OP is new and probably just doesn't get that SO is about accumulating a store of knowledge where others can benefit. Good thing the mods can undelete.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Such behaviour is simply rude. If the question is crap, it should be actually removed (with the exception, when there's some really good answer given, which honestly deserves upvotes). But if the question is simply removed, because the OP got what they wanted, it's rude and dishonest against you. It should be undeleted.

You should flag that question for moderator attention, if you can see the question. Otherwise, you can flag any of your posts and give the explanation you've done here. Well, once you've posted on meta, I suspect a moderator will react soon and undelete the question.

Comment: It appears as though it already has been undeleted

Comment: Meta effect :=)

Comment: Wow. That was fast. Glad I bothered to ask :)

Answer (score 26):

While this is allowed, it does seem like an abuse of the system in this case so I've undeleted the post.

The rules on deleting your own questions are that it has to be "unanswered". That is either:

- No answers
- Only one answer with a score of zero or less.

In any other circumstances you can't unilaterally delete your own content.

Comment: Do similar rules apply to moderator undeleted posts as for moderator deleted posts, i.e. will the asker now be prevented from deleting the question again because it was a diamond moderator that undeleted it?

Comment: @JonK - I don't know.

Comment: But the answer no longer has zero score :)

Comment: I think the rule of the one answer with a score of zero should change and should be come "only one answer with a score of less than zero"

Comment: Or maybe a cooling down period after posting in which a question can't be removed.