# How to deal with an user deleting a valid question with an answer -- and then asking it again?

Tags: discussion

I don't know how to deal with an user having deleted a (more or less) valid question with a (good) answer -- and then asking it again with only a minor change (added request for a `DISTINCT` clause is SQL):

- [how to select different tuples from the samle table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26327904/how-to-select-different-tuples-from-the-samle-table) (deleted)
- [how to select unique tuples from same table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26329068/how-to-select-unique-tuples-from-same-table)

As of myself, I would have *undeleted* the first question and marked the second as duplicate. Is this appropriate?

Comment: @gnat Correct: exact duplicate, but the answer does not completely satisfy me. Do I really need to flag moderator's attention?

Comment: check also answers to questions linked to it, for example [this one](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/269963/839601)

Comment: @gnat OK, thank you. I flagged for moderator's attention.

Comment: I've undeleted the older one, and pointed it to the more detailed newer version.